# How to put the json response in widget flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use my response data show in the widget. I post the data to my API then I get the return result.

My **response.body** is like this:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "Contents": {
                "Images": [
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                ],
                "Ages": [
                    {"age":"33"},
                    {"age":"34"}, 
                ],
                "Labels":[
                    {"label":"game"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is how to get the "**Images**", "**Ages**", and "**Labels**" details? I want to use these detail and put in my widget. Can I know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the below example that i have made : 
Follwing is the json file that you provided i have parsed locally.

```
{
    "responses": [{
        "Contents": {
            "Images": [{
                    "url": "https:URL"
                },
                {
                    "url": "https:URL"
                }
            ],
            "Ages": [{
                    "age": "33"
                },
                {
                    "age": "34"
                }
            ],
            "Labels": [{
                    "age": "33"
                }

            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Model class created for the json file:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final response = responseFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Response responseFromJson(String str) => Response.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseToJson(Response data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Response {
    List<ResponseElement> responses;

    Response({
        this.responses,
    });

    factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
        responses: List<ResponseElement>.from(json["responses"].map((x) => ResponseElement.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "responses": List<dynamic>.from(responses.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class ResponseElement {
    Contents contents;

    ResponseElement({
        this.contents,
    });

    factory ResponseElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseElement(
        contents: Contents.fromJson(json["Contents"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Contents": contents.toJson(),
    };
}

class Contents {
    List<Image1> images;
    List<Age> ages;
    List<Age> labels;

    Contents({
        this.images,
        this.ages,
        this.labels,
    });

    factory Contents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Contents(
        images: List<Image1>.from(json["Images"].map((x) => Image1.fromJson(x))),
        ages: List<Age>.from(json["Ages"].map((x) => Age.fromJson(x))),
        labels: List<Age>.from(json["Labels"].map((x) => Age.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "Ages": List<dynamic>.from(ages.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "Labels": List<dynamic>.from(labels.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Age {
    String age;

    Age({
        this.age,
    });

    factory Age.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Age(
        age: json["age"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "age": age,
    };
}

class Image1 {
    String url;

    Image1({
        this.url,
    });

    factory Image1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image1(
        url: json["url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
    };
}
```

This is the main UI file where you fetch and show the data, I have show your data in the list view.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/model.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Age> ages = List();
  List<Age> labels = List();
  List<Image1> image = List();

  // here i have taken the  json locally which you posted on stack
  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    givenFunction();
  }

  Future givenFunction() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    //http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    // you can make the http call above just uncomment is and comment the below line
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    // Here you can just replace down your response.body with jsonString
    final response = responseFromJson(jsonString);
    print(response.responses[0].contents.ages[0].age);
    //ages =response.responses[0].contents.
    for (int i = 0; i < response.responses[0].contents.ages.length; i++) {
      ages.add(response.responses[0].contents.ages[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < response.responses[0].contents.images.length; i++) {
      image.add(response.responses[0].contents.images[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < response.responses[0].contents.labels.length; i++) {
      labels.add(response.responses[0].contents.labels[i]);
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : SafeArea(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 400,
                          height: 100,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: ages.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 10,
                                  child: Center(child: Text(ages[index].age)),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 200,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: image.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 10,
                                  child: Center(child: Text(image[index].url)),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 200,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: labels.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 10,
                                  child: Center(child: Text(labels[index].age)),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(HomePage());
}
```

just taken a screen shot:
[image]

Just check it and let me know.

Comment: That's great it worked , just make a upvote so that it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory to make full models in Dart for decoding JSON.
You can simply do:

```
// Requires import
import 'dart:convert';

// Do like this
var data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Now data will automatically act as a map.

For example, if you want to access the label in the JSON example you provided, you can simply do:

```
data['responses'][0]['Contents']['Labels'][0]['label'].toString();
```

Coming to the actual part,
You need to shape your widgets according to your needs.

Create a Stateless or StatefulWidget whatever suits your needs and start laying out the design.

According to the JSON example that you posted, you need to show a list of images. So, you would probably generate a list of the Widgets based on the URLs and provide the list to perhaps a GridView in your build method.

Check this example I made:  [DartPad - JSON Widget example](https://dartpad.dev/55e4397952072726145e14ac2a907641)

Edit:

I used the exact JSON response you posted. It doesn't give me any errors.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final String mJson = '''
    {
    "responses": [
        {
            "Contents": {
                "Images": [
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                    {"url":"https:URL"}
                ],
                "Ages": [
                    {"age":"33"},
                    {"age":"34"}
                ],
                "Labels":[
                    {"label":"game"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
  ''';

  bool _loading = false;
  List<String> _infos = [];

  Widget _loadingBar() {
    return SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size.fromRadius(30),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
              Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MY APPS'), actions: <Widget>[
          _loading
              ? _loadingBar()
              : IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () => {
                        submit(context)
                            .then((res) => setState(() => _loading = false))
                      }),
        ]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: List.generate(_infos.length, (i) => Text(_infos[i]))),
        ));
  }

  Future<void> submit(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() => _loading = true);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    var data = jsonDecode(mJson);
    print(data);
    _infos.add(data['responses'][0].toString());
    _infos.add(data['responses'][0]['Contents'].toString());
    _infos.add(data['responses'][0]['Contents']['Images'][0]['url'].toString());
    _infos.add(data['responses'][0]['Contents']['Ages'][0]['age'].toString());
  }
}
```

Note: The code you posted later shouldn't work as you have declared non-final variables in a StatelessWidget class and also using setState. Also, in your Future submit(BuildContext context) you were supposed to jsonDecode(res) not demoJson. demoJson was not assigned. See the example I posted. I changed it to a stateful widget. I am having no trouble accessing any of the fields in the JSON example you gave. Your JSON example is a bit faulty though, it has extra ',' that might give error while decoding.

[image: Updated]

Comment: thank you for your help. When do I need to do models code? When I no need? I thought very need to do model code.

Comment: It completely depends on you. You can use models if you like. The only thing that would change is the way you access the data in case of models. For example, let's say, personData was a class model in my dartpad example. I would have to access the name as personData.name instead of personData['name'] and so on. so my text widget would have ${personData.name} and so on.

Comment: ohh I see, Thank you for your help

Comment: sorry sir, Why when I use my response data will show this error?  type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>'    I already edit my question

Comment: Are you typecasting the var data somewhere?

Comment: _InternalLinkedHashMap can't be converted to Map. This is an error that commonly occurs when you try to Convert them to Map forcefully. Please, make sure your code doesn't make this conversion anywhere. Even if you don't have a key in your _InternalLinkedHashMap, accessing that key's value will return null so you won't face a problem there either. Can you show the part of the code which throws the error according to the stack trace?

Comment: I did not convert to map. I just change the jsonDemo to my jsonDecode(response.body). I put var resp=jsonDecode(response.body). then I change the jsonDemo to resp. but get that error

Comment: Can you post your code here so I can check what is causing the error?